# Multiple CREATE's in an sql transaction with ANT

Tags: sql, sql-server, ant

Using sql with Ant transactions doesn't seem to let you perform more than one `CREATE` statement per transaction, so I've got around that by separating each `CREATE` statement into a seperate file. My build script looks something like this.

```
<sql
    driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://${dbserver}"
    userid="${username}"
    password="${password}"
>
    <transaction>use master</transaction>       
    <transaction>
        IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = N'${dbname}')
        DROP DATABASE [${dbname}]
    </transaction>
    <transaction>CREATE DATABASE [${dbname}]</transaction>
    <transaction>use [${dbname}]</transaction>
    <transaction src="${sqlscripts}mySproc.sql" />
</sql>
```

The problem is I now need to create a stored procedure that uses temporary tables but the build script won't do this in one transaction.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySproc] 
    @Username varchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #TEMP
    (
        Id              int,
        Description     nvarchar(max)
    );

    RETURN 1
END
```

Above is a simplified version of my sproc the Ant script throws an error because of using two `CREATE`'s  in one transaction. **Is there anyway around it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the fix is to add

```
delimiter="//"
```

to your sql tag.

```
<sql
    driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://${dbserver}"
    userid="${username}"
    password="${password}"

    delimiter="//" 
>
...
</sql>
```